# 403 Forbidden on rhel 8.4 using httpd userdir on a folder that is not /home

Tags: apache, rhel, selinux

I'm in the process of configuring our new server on RedHat 8.4 and making userdir work with httpd has been bugging me.
I've configured the file `/etc/httpd/conf.d/userdir.conf` as follows:

```bash
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    #
    # UserDir is disabled by default since it can confirm the presence
    # of a username on the system (depending on home directory
    # permissions).
    #
    UserDir enabled

    #
    # To enable requests to /~user/ to serve the user's public_html
    # directory, remove the "UserDir disabled" line above, and uncomment
    # the following line instead:
    # 
    UserDir public_html
</IfModule>

#
# Control access to UserDir directories. The following is an example
# for a site where these directories are restricted to read-only.
#
<Directory "/user/*/public_html">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I've used `/user` because we don't use the `/home` directory and I think that is part of the problem.
I read online that SELinux configures the folder with some degree of accessibility and I tried adding the same rule as `/home` to the `/user` folder:

```bash
/user/[^/]+/.+    all files    system_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
```

I also ran the command `setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs 1`, but since `/user` is not the home directory, it did nothing.

I also made sure to give access to the full path leading to `/public_html` and the folders inside.

If you have any ideas of things I can do that I haven't done already, I'll be happy to hear about it.

---

### Edit 1

after running `audit2allow -a`

```
#============= httpd_t ==============

#!!!! This avc can be allowed using one of the these booleans:
#     httpd_use_nfs, use_nfs_home_dirs, git_system_use_nfs
allow httpd_t nfs_t:dir read;

#!!!! This avc can be allowed using one of the these booleans:
#     httpd_use_nfs, use_nfs_home_dirs, git_system_use_nfs
allow httpd_t nfs_t:file getattr;

#============= init_t ==============

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow init_t portmap_port_t:tcp_socket name_connect;

#============= rhsmcertd_t ==============
allow rhsmcertd_t gpg_exec_t:file execute;

#============= sshd_t ==============

#!!!! This avc can be allowed using the boolean 'use_nfs_home_dirs'
allow sshd_t nfs_t:file read;

#============= system_dbusd_t ==============

#!!!! This avc has a dontaudit rule in the current policy
allow system_dbusd_t hi_reserved_port_t:tcp_socket name_bind;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow system_dbusd_t portmap_port_t:tcp_socket name_connect;
```

Comment: Hi, can you edit your question to add the result of `audit2allow -a` please?

Comment: Thanks, are the home dirs on an nfs ? Could you add the result of `ls -laZ /user` please?

Comment: yes they are on an nfs, we use nis to access the files from our main server if that can be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The needed context is `httpd_user_content_t` for readonly or `httpd_user_content_rw_t` for readwrite.

Also, since you have `UserDir public_html` in your configuration, you only need to label this directory.

Last, you might also need the `httpd_read_user_content` boolean for apache to access the `public_html` directory, but you can try without.

This should be enough then:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t '/user/[^/]+/public_html(/.*)?'
restorecon -RF /user
setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs 1
setsebool -P httpd_read_user_content 1
```

**Edit:** based on the result of your `audit2allow -a`, I guess the /user FS is NFS, so you could need to use the suggested boolean: `setsebool -P use_nfs_home_dirs 1`

Comment: Thank you so much ! `setsebool -P use_nfs_home_dirs 1` actually worked !